# ngx-editor showing placeholder although it has a value

Tags: angular, ngx-editor

I have a simple component using ngx-editor.
The html file is below:

```
<ng-container>

  <ngx-editor
    class="ngxEditor-view"
    [editor]="editorSummary"
    [ngModel]="test"
    [disabled]="true"
    [placeholder]="'No description available...'"
  ></ngx-editor>
</ng-container>
```

The ts class:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges, EventEmitter, Output, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {UntilDestroy} from '@ngneat/until-destroy';
import { Editor, Toolbar, Validators as EditorValidators } from 'ngx-editor';

@UntilDestroy({checkProperties: true})
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {

  editorSummary: Editor;
  test: string="123";
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
       this.editorSummary = new Editor();
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
  }

  closeMe(): void {
    this.isModalOpen = false;
    this.closeModal.emit();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.editorSummary.destroy();
  }

}
```

the editor is imported as follows:

```
import { NgxEditorModule } from 'ngx-editor';

@NgModule({
  
  imports: [

    NgxEditorModule

  ],
```

The text is never displayed, the message of the placeholder is shown instead. What can be the cause? I'm using it in several places in the application. There is only one page where it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see is that you want to use two way binding [(ngModel)] and not one way [ngModel]. Maybe this resouce could help you better understand the different Data Binding variants in Angular [Databinding in Angular](https://medium.com/geekculture/data-binding-in-angular-7b8394bbda8c).

Comment: It does not work, nor with two way binding, neither with one way. I don't know if it is related to binding. It is just showing the placeholder

Comment: Just for clarification, have you imported the FormsModule? Otherwise your ngModel won't work at all because it is part  of the FormsModule. After I imported it it worked for me.

Comment: It was missing some imports. Thanks!

Comment: Can you mark the answer as helpful? So that the next person searching for this issue can get a fast solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's [(ngModel)], not [ngModel].  Remember: banana in a box.

Comment: It's disabled. I added the () and it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

So I replicated your code. To fix your problem you will need to import the FormsModule as NgModel is a part of said module and won't work without it.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxEditorModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your issue and it's working correct, adding a stack blitz link here.

[workingDemo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c5mxnj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)